# Transparent pixel color - Go lang image

Tags: image, go, transparency

I'm trying to create a heat map from eye-tracker results (showing where on the screen was the user looking most frequently).

For pixels that the user looked frequently onto, I want to set non-transparent red color, for a bit less-frequent orange color, etc..
I'm using red to green color-scale.
But for the pixels with the least frequency, I want them to not only show green color, I want them to be transparent.

```
imgfile, err := os.Open("unchanged.jpeg")
defer imgfile.Close()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}

decodedImg, err := jpeg.Decode(imgfile)
img := image.NewRGBA(decodedImg.Bounds())

size := img.Bounds().Size()
for x := 0; x < size.X; x++ {
    for y := 0; y < size.Y; y++ {
        img.Set(x, y, decodedImg.At(x, y))
    }
}

// I change some pixels here with img.Set(...)

outFile, _ := os.Create("changed.png")
defer outFile.Close()
png.Encode(outFile, img)
```

The problem is that when I try to change color for example with `img.Set(x, y, color.RGBA{85, 165, 34, 50})` it doesn't actually color the pixel as averaged value depending on old and new color, it just shows some new, strange-looking color.

Image with alpha RGBA value set to 50: (transparent)

[image]

Image with alpha RGBA value set to 255: (opaque)

[image]

I'm using png image that as far as I know does support transparency.
Why does this happen? Any ideas that can solve this problem and make the least-frequently seen pixels appear transparent?

Thanks for every answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the `Set()` method sets (*overwrites*) the color of the pixel at the specified location. This is not what you want.

You want to combine the original color of the pixel with a color of your choosing, and you want this to be the final color.

For this to achieve, first you may query the original color with `Image.At()`, then combine the color with whatever you want to (you may do this by red, green, blue and alpha channels separately), and set the final color with the `Set()` method.

**Combining:**

Note that the `R`, `G`, `B`, `A` fields of the [color.RGBA](https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#RGBA) struct are alpha-premultiplied values, which means the `R` field for example holds the value of the color's red component multiplied by the alpha channel.

You may use the [`RGBA.RGBA()`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#RGBA.RGBA) method which returns all the fields as `uint32` values, and all will be in the range of `0..0xffff` so you may do operations on them without having to worry about overflow (max value of `uint8` is `255`, so even by adding 2 of them could easily overflow).

So when you combine 2 colors, you may combine by components. But note that type of these fields in `color.RGBA` is `uint8`, so after combining you have to convert the result to fit into 8 bits, so you have to shift right by 8.

A very simple combining: calculating average:

```
// Query:
x, y := 1, 1
r, g, b, a := img.At(x, y).RGBA()

// Combine:
col := color.RGBA{85, 165, 34, 50}
r2, g2, b2, a2 := col.RGBA()

col.R = uint8((r + r2) >> 9) // div by 2 followed by ">> 8"  is ">> 9"
col.G = uint8((g + g2) >> 9)
col.B = uint8((b + b2) >> 9)
col.A = uint8((a + a2) >> 9)

// Set new pixel:
img.Set(x, y, col)
```

You may incorporate this into a helper function:

```
func combine(c1, c2 color.Color) color.Color {
    r, g, b, a := c1.RGBA()
    r2, g2, b2, a2 := c2.RGBA()

    return color.RGBA{
        uint8((r + r2) >> 9), // div by 2 followed by ">> 8"  is ">> 9"
        uint8((g + g2) >> 9),
        uint8((b + b2) >> 9),
        uint8((a + a2) >> 9),
    }
}
```

And using it:

```
x, y := 1, 1
img.Set(x, y, combine(img.At(x, y), color.RGBA{85, 165, 34, 50}))
```

Please check out the [Alpha compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) page if you need realistic color compositing.